# ¿Como puedo detener un objectanimator y resetearlo a su posicion inicial? Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy usando un objectanimator para animar una imagen que se mueve horizontalmente y en bucle.
Ya se como darle los métodos de pause() y resume() para el mismo botón, pero me gustaría darle un método más que sea stop(), el cual haría que la imagen en movimiento se resetee y aparezca congelada en su posición inicial.

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void Stop(){

     animatorimagen.stop();
       
}
```

intenté darle a la imagen un .clearAnimation(); pero no me funciona

Answer (score 1):

Para reiniciar [ObjetAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator) debes remover sus listener y usar el método `cancel()` :

```
 animator.removeAllListeners();
 animator.cancel();
```

y posteriormente usar el método `onAnimationEnd()` en donde puedes iniciarlo nuevamente.

```
@Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            animator.setStartDelay(1000); //1 segundo.
            animator.start(); //Inicia.
  }
```